# Is there a way to queue and wait for individual events without buffering in Stream in Dart/Flutter?

Tags: flutter, asynchronous, dart, stream, dart-async

I am doing a notification Stream where each notification is shown for 5 seconds while business logic is allowed to keep adding new notification to the notification list.

Problem: Notification is shown as soon as they are called (or added to the Stream) which leads to many notification showing up at the same time

I don't have a code as I'm looking for a generic answer in Dart (whether it's Stream, StreamQueue or manipulating Stream controller)

Edit: I would like to work with Future rather than a fixed, periodic 5-second timer as mentioned above. For example: If a user dismiss the notification manually before 5-second is up, the next notification should appear immediately

Thank you

Comment: and when do you want to show them if for example 3 events occur? i mean 1 is shown right now and there are two other pending, when to show them?

Comment: @pskink hi, I want to show the next one as soon as the previous one finishes. when one is finished, it will be removed from the notification list. This will runs until no notifications are left and will continue when new notifications are added

Comment: so pause the sending stream when the notification is shown: `StreamSubscription.pause()` - the docs say: *"Request that the stream pauses events until further notice.

While paused, the subscription will not fire any events. If it receives events from its source, they will be buffered until the subscription is resumed. "*

Comment: @pskink that doesn't works because of this phrase: "they will be buffered until subscription is resumed". This leads to the first notification properly shows up alone but as soon as the first one is done, it will show the next few ones at the same time as they were buffered. I'm sure I'm missing something but don't know what that is yet

Comment: `var ss;
    ss = Stream.periodic(Duration(seconds: 5), (i) => i).asBroadcastStream() .listen((i) {
      print('enent $i');
      ss.pause();
      showDialog(context: context, builder: (ctx) {
        return AlertDialog(title: Text('event $i'), actions: [
          FlatButton(onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(ctx).pop();
            ss.resume();
          }, child: Text('ok')),
        ],);
      });
    });`

Comment: @pskink while your solution works for my question (which I should've asked differently, my bad). The exact case of mine deals with Future rather than a fixed, periodic 5 seconds. For example: if a user chooses to manually dismiss a notification before 5-second duration is up, it would need to immediately display the next noti.

Comment: i just used `Stream.periodic` as a simple source of events - you can use any other `Sink` that generates events

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think I have an idea what to do now

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggestion that may help you reach your goal:

```dart
    //Instantiate your Stream controller
    StreamController<Notification> notificationStreamController = StreamController.broadcast();
    //Map asynchronously  each content of your stream.
    notificationStreamController.stream.asyncMap((currentNotification) async {
      //Start your cancelableOperation here through a Future and await the result. It may for exemple return a boolean to say wheither or not the notificationDisplay was successfully
      //I suggest here a cancelableOperation in case you want to add a mechanisms to cancel the Future you will just start.
      return await startShowingNotificationAsync(currentNotification);
    }).listen((status) {
      //Start listening for the content of the new stream so that the content of the stream will start continuously proceed.
      print("Notification_was_displaed successfully = $status");
    });
```

In another hand, each time a new Notification should be enqueue, just call the StramController as follow:

```dart
Notification notification = ....//Some new Notification.class instance
//Below we push a new element in the stream waiting to be listened  by the listener started above
notificationStreamController.add(notification);
```

Hope it helps!